# Can't separate header and source files in JNI

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

in JNI folder:

```
//File foo.h
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    void Funny();
};
#endif /* FOO_H_ */
```

---

```
//File foo.cpp
#include "foo.h"

cv::string bar[1] = {"FOO"};
Foo::Foo() {

}
void Foo::Funny() {

}
```

Then, when I call:

```
Foo foo;
foo.Funny();
```

ndk-build complains:

```
error: undefined reference to 'Foo::Foo()
error: undefined reference to 'Foo::Funny()
```

However, if I put the function implementation in the header file like this:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
    void Funny();
};

Foo::Foo() {

}
void Foo::Funny() {

}
#endif /* FOO_H_ */
```

The compiler then happily compiles my code.

How could I separate function prototypes and their implementation in JNI?

UPDATE: Here's my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := native.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_MODULE     := native
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: There's no problem doing this in general.  It sounds like you aren't linking things right.  You may want to post your makefile.

Comment: I am not familiar with `ndk-build`, but it looks as if you fail to link `foo.o` into your executable.

Comment: @GabeSechan Hi I've included my makefile.

Comment: So why isn't `Foo.cpp` included in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`? If it's not, how do you expect the implementations of `Foo()` and `Funny()` to be included when your library is linked?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Gezz I didn't know that the implementation file must be declared in the makefile. I thought the .cpp file would be automatically searched each time the header is included.

Comment: No sir. The compiler needs to header file to tell it what functions exist, but then the linker -- the tool that actually builds the library out of all the compiled code -- needs to put all the compiled object files together, so you have to list them by name.

Comment: The reason it doesn't link all the .cpp files automatically is that you may not want to do that.  For example, if you have code that draws to the screen you may have 3 or 4 versions for different OSes, each implemented in different files.  You'd only want to link in one of those, not all of them.  A feature I've frequently wished existed for Java/Android, rather than it sucking up every .java file it sees.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined reference is outputted by the linker, not by the Compiler. This means there is no translation unit containing the functions you have used in your code. Telling by the Android.mk file I'd say foo.cpp is missing in your LOCAL_SRC_FILES Statement.